# Smile - Model Persistence - How to write models to HDFS?

Tags: scala, hdfs, smile

I am trying to use [Smile](https://haifengl.github.io) in my Scala project which uses Spark and HDFS. For reusability of my models, I need to write them to HDFS.

Right now I am using the [write](https://github.com/haifengl/smile/blob/3a50d77dda8a9959ed418c1a5d779d5d5b2d3c99/scala/src/main/scala/smile/io.scala#L33) object, checking if the path exists beforehand and creating it if it does not (otherwise it would throw a FileNotFoundException) :

```
import java.nio.file.Paths

val path: String = "hdfs:/my/hdfs/path"
val outputPath: Path = Paths.get(path)
val outputFile: File = outputPath.toFile
if(!outputFile.exists()) {
  outputFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();  // This is a no-op if it exists
  outputFile.createNewFile();
}
write(mySmileModel, path)
```

but this creates locally the path "hdfs:/my/hdfs/path" and writes the model in it, instead of actually writing to HDFS.
Note that using a spark model and its [save](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/5197c5d2e7648d75def3e159e0d2aa3e20117105/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/util/ReadWrite.scala#L287) method works:

```
mySparkModel.save("hdfs:/my/hdfs/path")
```

**Therefore my question: How to write a Smile model to HDFS?**
Similarly, if I manage to write a model to HDFS, I will probably also wonder how to read a model from HDFS.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look to https://index.scala-lang.org/pierrenodet/spark-smile/spark-smile/0.0.2?target=_2.11

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you finally find a solution?

Comment: @leleogere yes let me add my own solution as an answer

Comment: Nice solution, I think this is the way to go. Thank you

Comment: @leleogere Welcome! glad it could help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I solved my problem by writing my own save method for my wrapper class, which roughly amounts to:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FSDataInputStream, FSDataOutputStream, FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import java.io.{ObjectInputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

val path: String = /my/hdfs/path
val file: Path = new Path(path)
val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
val hdfs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(path), conf)
val outputStream: FSDataOutputStream = hdfs.create(file)
val objectOutputStream: ObjectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream)
objectOutputStream.writeObject(model)
objectOutputStream.close()
```

Similarly, for loading the saved model I wrote a method doing roughly the following:

```
val conf: Configuration = new Configuration()
val path: String = /my/hdfs/path
val hdfs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(path), conf)
val inputStream: FSDataInputStream = hdfs.open(new Path(path))
val objectInputStream: ObjectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream)
val model: RandomForest = objectInputStream.readObject().asInstanceOf[RandomForest]
```